# Duty of al-fec in Mpeg media transport?

Tags: video-streaming, media, crc, mpeg, mpeg-dash

During packet transmission, we have packet loss and packet error. I wish to know al-fec in Mpeg media transport , is for recovering packet loss or packet errors or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There key standard for Forward Error Correction in the broadcast world is 'ST 2022-1:2007 - Forward Error Correction for Real-Time Video/Audio Transport Over IP Networks'.

The is, unfortunately, not a standard you can openly view without buying a copy (AFAIK) but the focus of the standard is on packet loss, and the recovery of a lost packet using redundant FEC packets associated with rows and columns of video packets.

I think the distinction between corrupted and lost may be a bit arbitrary in practice in this case anyway, though, as it is likely that a receiver will just treat a corrupted packet as lost (when the checksum does not match for example) and it can then re-create the 'lost' packet via FEC.